# Progress bar now showing VB

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have a project that loads all the graphics dinamically and I manage to add the to the form but I don't know why the progress bar is the only one not showing, this is the way I'm doing it:

```
    Dim newprogressBar As New ProgressBar
```

and to add it to the form

```
    Me.Controls.Add(newprogressBar)
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check its size & location.

Comment: I did set the size and location, but did not paste it here, its solved now thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have other controls on form, they may are in front of your progressbar. try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim newprogressBar As New ProgressBar
        Me.Controls.Add(newprogressBar)
        newprogressBar.BringToFront()
    End Sub
```